# How to delete GitHub project?

Tags: github

I know how to close a GitHub project (clicking the hamburger menu of https://github.com/sunknudsen?tab=projects and then "Close"), but how can I permanently delete a project?

The question relates to a GitHub [project](https://github.com/features/project-management), not a repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/deleting-a-project-board.

Click **Menu**, then **Edit** and finally **Delete project**.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

novice in DotNet's answer (Jan 26, 2021) is for projects v1 aka classic.
This is the link for projects v2:
https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/managing-your-project/closing-and-deleting-your-projects

Navigate to project -> ...(top right) -> Settings -> Delete this project